# How to get a percentage from JSON in android?

Tags: java, android, math, casting

For example,  there is a json obj contain a percentage field

e.g.

height: "63.6585%"

So I get it using like `json.getString("height");`

The problem is how can I cast it and do some calculation? I tried parseFloat but return error:

```
12-13 18:58:32.372: E/AndroidRuntime(14361): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "63.6585%"
```

What I would like is to use it like:

```
int left = Math.round((Float.parseFloat(mediaObj.getString("height")) * 1906) / 100);
```

How to fix it? thanks

Comment: hi are u get height values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get it as a String, remove the last character "%", and then parse it to float or double.

Answer (score 3):

Do this way:

```
 String str = "63.6585%";
 float per = Float.parseFloat(str.split("%")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, sorry for new to java, come from php , it seems php is more intelligent

I solved it by

```
Math.round((Float.parseFloat(mediaObj.getString("top").replace("%","")) * 2731) / 100);
```

Also, I wonder are there different if I use 2731.0f instead of 2731?

Thanks

Comment: Its not about the intelligence of any programming language, its just simple conversion logic, just different syntax for different languages. Logic remains same for every language.

Answer (score 0):

use that

Double k=Double.parseDouble(your string);

k is your output